# Not open rtsp:// and market:// both url in Webview app

Tags: android, webview, google-play, rtsp

I make webview application. i want open both urls "rtsp://" and "market://" in default video player and play store.
i use this code. but problem is "market://" url open in play store correctly but rtsp link not open in default video player. error says page not found.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//private Button button;
private WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    startWebView("http://google.com");


    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    this.webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
      public void onDownloadStart(String paramAnonymousString1, String paramAnonymousString2, String paramAnonymousString3, String paramAnonymousString4, long paramAnonymousLong)
      {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(paramAnonymousString1));
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
      }
    });
    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView paramAnonymousWebView, String paramAnonymousString)
      {
        if (paramAnonymousString.startsWith("rtsp"))
        {
          Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(paramAnonymousString));
          MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
          return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(paramAnonymousWebView, paramAnonymousString);
      }
    });


    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
                    host.startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    view.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });



    }
```

Comment: Believe the multiple calls to webView.setWebViewClient() are overriding each other. Play store works because its the last call. But regardless, page not found is a totally obvious answer to your question.

Comment: i want open both urls . give me solution.